# Css jQuery issue with simple drop down menu

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I have provided the test website link below:
http://www.naughtyfancydress.com/html/outfit.html

I am trying to integrate a simple drop down menu to the "Themes" link, but no matter which implementation of a drop down I use, the menu items do not show past the navbar div.

I have set the z-index but short of setting the height of navbar to 300px with masses of black space there is not way i have found to just make the menu appear like the original website at http://www.naughtyfancydress.com

S.O. is now the last resort for me as the guy who did the css is not helpful at all.

NOTE: if you're at work; this is a fancy dress website so expect Halloween, cop costumes and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#navbar` has `overflow:hidden`. Remove it. *clears history*

edit: also give the ul's some z-index value.

```
#navbar ul ul{
z-index:4000;
}
```

*again clears history*

Comment: I have made the suggestion.. no luck - http://www.naughtyfancydress.com/html/michael/outfit.html

Comment: Hi michael, pls check the link, its kinda working but still a little messed.

Comment: Ok, ive taken it from here, but you suggestions were very helpful in getting it somewhat working.